# how to do ng-repeat in table formate?

Tags: angularjs

[image]

```
$scope.testArray = [{no : 1, firstname: jenson, lastname: raby , details :["software engineer","qualification - b tech"] },{no : 2, firstname: johnson, lastname: raby , details :["designer ","qualification - bsc"] }];
```

This is the array which i need to print in html using angular js ng- repeat ,can anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`

Take a look at the following code segment.

```
<table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            No
        </th>
        <th>
            First Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Last Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Details
        </th>
    </tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="item in testArray">
        <td>{{item.no}}</td>
        <td>{{item.firstname}}</td>
        <td>{{item.lastname}}</td>
        <td  ng-click="item.show=!item.show">
            <span ng-if="!item.show">Details</span>
            <span ng-if="item.show">Less</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="item.show" ng-repeat="detail in item.details" ng-repeat-end>
        <td colspan="4">{{detail}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In the preceding code I have tried to do the thing you wanted to do. Hope it will help you.

Comment: can you give an another help for showing the details only after clicking on the details text in table header

Comment: Here you go. I have edited my answer as per your request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-table](http://ng-table.com/) module for display tabular data.

Comment: thank you for your replay, here i need to display the details in a single row which i mentioned on question, can you give how to print that in html using ng-repeat or some other method

Answer (score 0):

Please see here
link http://jsfiddle.net/vp7uge7e/

```
$scope.testArray = [{no : 1, firstname: 'jenson', lastname: 'raby' , details :   ["software engineer","qualification - b tech"] },{no : 2, firstname: 'johnson', lastname: 'raby' , details :["designer ","qualification - bsc"] }];
```

I have used this one
Hope this help you

Comment: Yes even ng-table is best solution to use in angular way

Comment: This one is not as per my question so i can't make this as correct, anyway thnaks for your comment